# Cognito Identity returning the same ID every time - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to obtain a new Cognito Identity during the user signup process. Here's a code snippet:

```
aws.config.credentials = new aws.CognitoIdentityCredentials(unauthCred);
aws.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    var id = aws.config.credentials.identityId;
}
```

I am expecting this to give me a new unique id every call. However, I am getting the same id every time. Is this the expected behavior? What can I do to get the behavior I want?

Comment: Your callback function does not test the value of err. Perhaps your call to get() failed and you are ignoring the error, hence always seeing the same value in aws.config.credentials.identityId.

Comment: I'm error checking in the main code. The get() function is completing successfully. Have you encountered this in your implementation? Or are you able to get a new ID each call?

Answer (score 1):

The identityId is cached, so you would get a new identityId if you clear the cached one, or call [GetId](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetId.html) API.

P.S.: Cognito Identity Credentials are not really suited for a server side use case. Can you please elaborate your use case, so that we can help you in a better manner?

-Rachit